# What is the best way to perform multiple filter operations on spark streaming dataframe read from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I need to apply multiple filters on a DataFrame read from a Kafka topic and publish output of each of these filter to an external system (like another Kafka topic).

I have read the kafkaDF like this

```scala
val kafkaDF: DataFrame = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "try.kafka.stream")
  .load()
  .select(col("topic"), expr("cast(value as string) as message"))
  .filter(col("message").isNotNull &&  col("message") =!= "")
  .select(from_json(col("message"), eventsSchema).as("eventData"))
  .select("eventData.*")
```

I am able to run a `foreachBatch` on this Dataframe and then iterate over the list of filters to get the filtered data which then can be published to a kafka topic, as shown below

```
kafkaDF.writeStream
  .foreachBatch { (batch: DataFrame, _: Long) =>
    // List of filters that needs to be applied
    filterList.par.foreach(filterString => {
      val filteredDF = batch.filter(filterString)
      // Add some columns. 
      // Do some operations based on different filter
      filteredDF.toJSON.foreach(value => {
        // Publish a message to Kafka 
      })
    })
  }
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("60 seconds"))
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

But, I am not sure if this is the best way given so many iterations. Is there a better way than doing it like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to write data from one Kafka topic into multiple Kafka topics you can create a column called "topic" in a *single* Dataframe when writing to Kafka. The value in this column then defines the topic in which a record will be produced. This allows you to write to as many different Kafka topics as required.

Therefore, I would just apply your filter logic as a when/otherwise condition or, if more complex, as a UDF.

Below is an example code that should get you started. Based on the `value` of the consumed Kafka message, a column called "topic" gets created in the `filteredDf`. If `value = 1` then the Dataframe record gets produced into the topic called "out1", and otherwise the recod gets produced into topic called "out2".

```scala
val inputDf = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "try.kafka.stream")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key", "CAST(value AS STRING) as value", "partition", "offset", "timestamp")

val filteredDf = inputDf.withColumn("topic", when(filter, lit("out1")).otherwise(lit("out2")))


val query = filteredDf
  .select(
    col("key"),
    to_json(struct(col("*"))).alias("value"),
    col("topic"))
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/michael/sparkCheckpoint/1/")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

---

EDIT: (I might have misunderstood your question initially)

If you just want to find a good way to apply multiple filters out of your `filterList` you can combine them using `foldLeft`:

```scala
val filter1 = col("value") === 1
val filter2 = col("key") === 1
val filterList = List(filter1, filter2)
val filterAll = filterList.tail.foldLeft(filterList.head)((f1, f2) => f1.and(f2))

println(filterAll)
((value = 1) AND (key = 1))
```

Then apply `.filter(filterAll)` to your Dataframe.

Comment: thanks! this makes sense if I could have joined the filters. However, in this case I need to apply the filter and do different operations based on that. e.g. consider I am reading log messages from Kafka and my filters are to find error, warning, info, debug etc message and create an importance score column for each type of message and then push them to separate topics in Kafka